# How to Use the Pygame Rect

Tags: python, function, pygame, rect

I have been experimenting with Pygame, and have come across a problem that I could not find the answer to. In [this paste](http://pastebin.com/yAXjcZzi), my basic game framework is exhibited. How can i complete my `ballSnapLeft()` definition correctly?

Edit: I am not looking for my code to be completed, but I am looking for someone to explain how the 'Rect' class(?) works, and how it could be applied.

Edit2: I have tried to use the x and y coordinates to do so, but I think there is a simpler way that can actually work, instead of using brute coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Making Games With Python and Pygame](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1469901730):

> **myRect.left** The int value of the X-coordinate of the left side of the
> rectangle.
>
> **myRect.right**
> The int value of the X-coordinate of the right side of the rectangle.
>
> **myRect.top**
> The int value of the Y-coordinate of the top side of the rectangle.
>
> **myRect.bottom**
> The int value of the Y-coordinate of the bottom side.

Because all of these attributes return integers, that's probably why your code isn't working.

Also, if your goal with `ballSnapLeft()` is to move the ball to a position away from the player, `ballRect.right = playerRect.left - distance` would only change the X coordinate of the rect. To make the ball also move in the Y coordinate you could do something like

```
def ballSnapTop():
    ballRect.top = playerRect.bottom - distance
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting an error when you execute `ballRect.right = playerRect.left - (0, 1)`?

`ballRect.right` and `ballRect.left`, along with the related `top`, `bottom`, `width`, `height` values, are `int` types and can't have tuples added or subtracted from them.

You might want to take a look at the [pygame.Rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) documentation, and consider using `pygame.Rect.move(x,y)` which will shift the coordinates of the rectangle for you.

It's also worth noting that if you change, for example, `myRect.topleft`, then the corresponding `top`, `left`, `bottom`, etc... values will change as well so that the `rect` translates and preserves its size.